# Hide buttons if user doesn't belong to any of Django groups

Tags: python-3.x, django

My problem is that I want to hide the button from all users who are not in group1 and group2 or in both groups. I did the following thing but it seems doesn't work at all.

My views.py:

```
def is_group1(user):
  return user.groups.filter(name='Group1').exists()

def is_group2(user):
  return user.groups.filter(name='Group2').exists()

def employee_list(request):
  groups = [g.name for g in request.user.groups.filter(name__in=['Group1', 'Group2'])]
  context = {'employee_list': Employee.objects.filter(dept__in=groups)}
  return render(request, 'employee_register/employee_list.html', context)
```

My little example of employee_list.html:

```
    <form>
    {% if user.is_group1 %}
      <button formaction="{% url 'employee_insert' %}">Add</button>
    {% if user.is_group2%}
      <button formaction="{% url 'employee_insert' %}">Add</button>
    {% else %}
      <p>You are not logged</p>
    {% endif %}
    </form>
```

Any thoughts how I can implement this ?

Comment: What output or errors are you getting?

Comment: Output: 'You are not logged'. But my groups are 100% correct.

Comment: You only showed functions that take a user as parameter but in your template, you are calling the method on a user object. However you cannot pass parameters to functions from Django templates. Instead, move that logic to the view and pass its result to the template.

Answer (score 0):

In order to hide a button if a user does not belong to a group, you can implement following method:

First, set-up categories using AbstractUser:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

    class StatusType(models.Model):
        VOLUNTEER = "VOLUNTEER"
        MANAGER = "MANAGER"
        EMPLOYEE = "EMPLOYEE"
        STATUS = [
            (MANAGER, "Manager"),
            (EMPLOYEE, "Employee"),
            (VOLUNTEER, "Volunteer"),
        ]

    status_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        choices=StatusType.STATUS, 
        default=StatusType.VOLUNTEER,
        verbose_name="Statut")
```

Then, in your template, add this to toggle the button:

```
{% if user.status_type == "MANAGER" %}
       <form action="{% url 'interviews:advocacy_topic_create' %}" id="topic-create">
           <button type="submit">Create</button>
       </form>
{% endif %}
```

You should not create a view depending on each type of user.